# Bootstrap date time picker

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the  date time picker as explained here https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#minimum-setup, I have downloaded the `js` file `css` file to the directory `js` and `css`. But the calendar is not popup up when click on icon.

```js
 $(function() {
   $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
 });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: check if styles and scripts are working

Comment: You can actually add moment js after the main jquery.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

All scripts should be imported in order:

1. jQuery and Moment.js
2. Bootstrap js file
3. Bootstrap datepicker js file

Bootstrap-datetimepicker requires `moment.js` to be loaded before `datepicker.js`.

**Working snippet:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the difference in this and the answer that I posted

Comment: @Nitheesh the explanation ;)

Comment: This works with version 3.3.7 of bootstrap stylesheet but not 4.1.1. I need to use 4.1.1 for other reasons and I don't know what to do :(

Comment: It isn't working to me =( Its only working after clicked 3 times. The first time get error: Uncaught bootstrap-datetimepicker requires Moment.js to be loaded first. Second time refreshed the page get the error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function. Just the 3rd time it works. Always. Any fix, please? ty

Answer (score 14):

In order to run the bootstrap date time picker you need to include `moment.js` as well. This is a dependency of `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` so ensure to import `moment.js` before `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js`.

You should import the dependent libraries first before the actual libraries. Hece the order will be.

- jquery.js
- bootstrap.js (Bootstrap requires jQuery)
- moment.js
- bootstrap-datetimepicker.js (Bootstrap Datetimepicker requires Moment JS)

Here is the working code sample in your case.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
    
      <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"> -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css"> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    
    <body>
    
       <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                });
            </script>
          </div>
       </div>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 7):

Try This:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
            <input type='text' class="form-control" />
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
          $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
        });
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This work for date only, I need date and time together, what wrong with the  method I used in my question.

Comment: @Gaurav Srivastava, Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45416906/how-to-create-dynamic-datetimepicker-value

Comment: @SuccessMan let me check

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to give local path. just give **cdn** link of **bootstrap datetimepicker**. and it works.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker').datepicker();
            });
        </script>
      </div>
   </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need both time and date together.

Answer (score 2):

> You can simply use

```
<label for="birthdaytime">Birthday (date and time):</label>
<input type="datetime-local" id="birthdaytime" name="birthdaytime">
```

- Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here the positioning of the css and script links makes a to of difference. Bootstrap executes in CSS and then Scripts fashion. So if you have even one script written at incorrect place it makes a lot of difference. You can follow the below snippet and change your code accordingly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker-standalone.css"> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
     <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                        <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
                });
            </script>
          </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might provide a bit of narrative context for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign();
    
      $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
           icons: {
               time: "fa fa-clock-o",
               date: "fa fa-calendar",
               up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
               down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
               previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
               next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
               today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
               clear: 'fa fa-trash',
               close: 'fa fa-remove'
           }
        });

        $('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
           format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
           icons: {
               time: "fa fa-clock-o",
               date: "fa fa-calendar",
               up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
               down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
               previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
               next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
               today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
               clear: 'fa fa-trash',
               close: 'fa fa-remove'
           }
        });

        $('.timepicker').datetimepicker({
//          format: 'H:mm',    // use this format if you want the 24hours timepicker
           format: 'h:mm A',    //use this format if you want the 12hours timpiecker with AM/PM toggle
           icons: {
               time: "fa fa-clock-o",
               date: "fa fa-calendar",
               up: "fa fa-chevron-up",
               down: "fa fa-chevron-down",
               previous: 'fa fa-chevron-left',
               next: 'fa fa-chevron-right',
               today: 'fa fa-screenshot',
               clear: 'fa fa-trash',
               close: 'fa fa-remove'

           }
        });
});
```

```css
html *{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.title h3{
    font-size: 25px !important;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    line-height: 1.4em !important;
    font-weight: 300;
}

/* inputs */

.container .bmd-form-group .bmd-label-static {
    top: .35rem;
    left: 0;
    font-size: .875rem;
}

.container .bmd-form-group .form-control, .bmd-form-group input::placeholder, .bmd-form-group label {
    line-height: 1.1;
}

.container .form-control, .is-focused .form-control {
    background-image: linear-gradient(0deg,#9c27b0 2px,
    rgba(156,39,176,0) 0),linear-gradient(0deg,#d2d2d2 1px,hsla(0,0%,82%,0) 0) !important;
}

.is-focused [class*=" bmd-label"], .is-focused [class^=bmd-label] {
    color: #9c27b0 !important;
}
.form-control {
    background: no-repeat bottom,50% calc(100% - 1px);
    background-size: 0 100%,100% 100%;
    border: 0;
    height: 36px;
    transition: background 0s ease-out;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 14px !important;
}

/* dropdown */

.dropdown-menu.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.open {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
    top: 0;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 4px;
    width: 19em;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .list-unstyled {
    margin: 0;
}

.sr-only,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="incrementHours"]::after,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="incrementMinutes"]::after,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="decrementHours"]::after,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="decrementMinutes"]::after,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="showHours"]::after,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="showMinutes"]::after,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="togglePeriod"]::after,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="clear"]::after,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="today"]::after,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .picker-switch::after,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.prev::after,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.next::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 0;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget {
    list-style: none;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget a:hover {
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget a .btn:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu {
    padding: 4px;
    width: 19em;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.timepicker-sbs {
        width: 38em;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 991px) {
    .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.timepicker-sbs {
        width: 38em;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.timepicker-sbs {
        width: 38em;
    }
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.bottom:before,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.bottom:after {
    right: auto;
    left: 12px;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.top {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 27px;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.top.open {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: 27px;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.pull-right:before {
    left: auto;
    right: 6px;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.dropdown-menu.pull-right:after {
    left: auto;
    right: 7px;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .list-unstyled {
    margin: 0;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget a[data-action] {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-width: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #9c27b0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget a[data-action]:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget a[data-action]:hover span {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #9c27b0;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget a[data-action]:active {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .timepicker-hour,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .timepicker-minute,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .timepicker-second {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.125rem;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget button[data-action] {
    width: 38px;
    height: 38px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 0;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="incrementHours"]::after {
    content: "Increment Hours";
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="incrementMinutes"]::after {
    content: "Increment Minutes";
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="decrementHours"]::after {
    content: "Decrement Hours";
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="decrementMinutes"]::after {
    content: "Decrement Minutes";
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="showHours"]::after {
    content: "Show Hours";
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="showMinutes"]::after {
    content: "Show Minutes";
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="togglePeriod"]::after {
    content: "Toggle AM/PM";
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="clear"]::after {
    content: "Clear the picker";
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .btn[data-action="today"]::after {
    content: "Set the date to today";
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .picker-switch {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .picker-switch::after {
    content: "Toggle Date and Time Screens";
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .picker-switch td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    line-height: inherit;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .picker-switch td span {
    line-height: 2.5;
    height: 2.5em;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 2px 0px !important;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table.table-condensed tr>td {
    text-align: center;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td>div,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th>div {
    text-align: center;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th {
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.picker-switch {
    width: 145px;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.disabled,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.disabled:hover {
    background: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.prev span,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.next span {
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 27px;
    width: 27px;
    line-height: 28px;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.prev::after {
    content: "Previous Month";
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.next::after {
    content: "Next Month";
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table th.dow {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table thead tr:first-child th {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table thead tr:first-child th:hover span,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table thead tr:first-child th.picker-switch:hover {
    background: #eee;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td>div {
    border-radius: 3px;
    height: 54px;
    line-height: 54px;
    width: 54px;
    text-align: center;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.cw>div {
    font-size: .8em;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #999;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.day>div {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    color: #3C4858;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.minute>div,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.hour>div {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.day:hover>div,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.hour:hover>div,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.minute:hover>div,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.second:hover>div {
    background: #eee;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.old>div,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.new>div {
    color: #999;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.today>div {
    position: relative;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.today>div:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0 0 7px 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #9c27b0;
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    right: 4px;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.active>div,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.active:hover>div {
    background-color: #9c27b0;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 7px 10px -5px rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.4);
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.active.today:before>div {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.disabled>div,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td.disabled:hover>div {
    background: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 3px 3px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td span:hover {
    background: #eee;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td span.active {
    background-color: #9c27b0;
    color: #fff;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td span.old {
    color: #999;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td span.disabled,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget table td span.disabled:hover {
    background: none;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    cursor: not-allowed;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .timepicker-picker span,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .timepicker-hours span,
.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget .timepicker-minutes span {
    border-radius: 50% !important;
}

.bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget.usetwentyfour td.hour {
    height: 27px;
    line-height: 27px;
}

.btn.btn-primary {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #9c27b0 !important;
    border-color: #9c27b0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.12);
}

.btn.btn-primary:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 14px 26px -12px rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.42), 0 4px 23px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 8px 10px -5px rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.2);
}

/* footer */

footer{
    margin-top:150px;
    color: #555;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 25px;
    font-weight: 300;
    
}
.footer p{
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
footer p a{
    color: #555;
    font-weight: 400;
}

footer p a:hover {
    color: #9f26aa;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.form-control:focus{
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" integrity="sha384-wXznGJNEXNG1NFsbm0ugrLFMQPWswR3lds2VeinahP8N0zJw9VWSopbjv2x7WCvX" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesgeet" href="https://rawgit.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit/master/assets/css/material-kit.css">
</head>

<body>
    
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <div class="title">
          <h3>Datetime Picker</h3>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="label-control">Datetime Picker</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker" value="10/05/2016">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="label-control">Date Picker</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" value="10/10/2016">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="label-control">Time Picker</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control timepicker" value="14:00">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </div>
    
    <footer class="footer text-center ">
        <p>Made with <a href="https://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit/index.html" target="_blank">Material Kit</a> by Creative Tim</p>
    </footer>
    
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.12.6/dist/umd/popper.js" integrity="sha384-fA23ZRQ3G/J53mElWqVJEGJzU0sTs+SvzG8fXVWP+kJQ1lwFAOkcUOysnlKJC33U" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.js" integrity="sha384-CauSuKpEqAFajSpkdjv3z9t8E7RlpJ1UP0lKM/+NdtSarroVKu069AlsRPKkFBz9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit/master/assets/js/core/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit/master/assets/js/core/bootstrap-material-design.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit/master/assets/js/plugins/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit/master/assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit/master/assets/js/material-kit.js"></script>
</body>
```

try this