# need timepicker in 24 hr format to be added inline

Tags: javascript, html, timepicker

I am new to javascript and need a timepicker in 24 hr format.. while there are several timepickers available online but most are with 12 hr format with complex code and external files. there are many jquery and javascript code available for datepicker but none is available for timepicker.

i am using this timepicker but it's not working.. the datepicker works fine.. What changes can be made?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate: 0, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
  } );
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
  $("#timepicker1").timepicker();
  });
  </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="inputvalidation.js"></script>


    </head>
```

Comment: Please, create a fiddle and let me know when you have done so. By addressing me this way: @lajosarpad in your answer command

Comment: @lajosarpad i have tried a new code but i just want make this work.. it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)?

Using *bootstrap-datetimepicker*, if you need 24 hour format I believe you must edit `Moment.js` like this:

```
moment().format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss");
```

> Format also dictates what components are shown, e.g. MM/dd/YYYY will not display the time picker.

[Here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) is full document of this tool format.

**UPDATE**

I understand that you are confused because of diverse libraries that used in this tools. This question already asked before in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035730/bootstrap-date-time-picker). You are able to copy and paste the libraries from there to your page as they are all external links to existing servers.

Comment: go to https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/ then follow MANUAL part. I assure you its simple and you can find your way. just try it.

Comment: there is a lot of code and files given.. what should i download

Answer (score 0):

In HTML 5 the recommendation allows for a:

```
<Input type="time">
```

The 24 hour in this case depends on the client, but this solution is simple.

Alternatively and with better responsive properties a drop down list could represent 0-24 hours and another drop down could represent 0-60 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML 5 the recommendation allows for a:

```
<input type="time">
```

The time input format depends on the client's browser.

An alternative could utilise the input type='number' input with a min 0 - 24 for hours and one with min 0 - 60 minutes.

An additional alternative could resolve with better responsive properties with a select drop down for hours and minutes.

Comment: It is not timepicker