# Bootstrap datetime picker plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Here is a simple DatePicker that works.

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css"/>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
      var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
      var options={
        format: '"dd/MM/yyyy - hh:ii"',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
      };
      date_input.datetimepicker(options);
    })
</script>
<head>
<body> 
  <div class="form-group"> <!-- Date input -->
      <label class="control-label" for="date">Date</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text"/>
  </div>
</body>
```

How should the above code change in order to make it use a DATETIME picker? Im assuming I need to use different plugins within the header? Please could someone advise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap date time picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035730/bootstrap-date-time-picker)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
          <input type='text' class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Source: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Make working in SO with help from :https://stackoverflow.com/a/40036266/4091337
and @Abhishek in comments